# exit code 14 error in mongodb container, I'm using mongodb container with with volume path then received exit code 14 error

Tags: mongodb, docker-compose, stack, docker-swarm

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
   mongo:
      image: mongo
      working_dir: /c/data/
      ports:
       - 27017:27017
      deploy:
        replicas: 1
      volumes:
        - /c/data/:/data/db
```

I am tried that above stack file and I'm receiving exit code 14 error please give me the solution about the error,

Comment: `working_dir` refers to a directory inside the container, not on the host. you need to make sure `/c/data/` can be created on the node where the container runs (it is quite a weird path...). It is generally better to avoid using host volumes when working with stacks.

Answer (score 11):

Delete everything from `/c/data/`, in case there are some data from older version of Mongo

Comment: Yes, it is work but do I have to delete it every time? If I delete everything from `/c/data/` then it's work so I start the db and the files are recreated. When I restart the db I get exit code 14 error.

Comment: I guess so.. only in case of upgrade/downgrade's.. I didn't found any workarounds at the moment

Comment: This worked for me, along with using the `-d` flag.

Comment: If I was ok with deleting data, then why would I make shared volume?

Answer (score 10):

In your terminal:

```
docker system prune
```

Works for me. Kew Approves =)

*Please, be careful! it clears everything!!

Comment: works, it will clear the mess

Comment: This helped me quickly resolve a disk full issue today.  But i would advise that you proceed with care, and perhaps by pruning containers without touching your volumes.

Answer (score 2):

It depends how you get up the service, for example use:

`docker-compose up -d` (on Windows)

instead of `docker-compose up`. In this way you have the control on terminal to call `docker-compose down` and the MongoDB process can terminate correctly.

Comment: This worked for me, but I also had the issue of old data files that I had to delete.

Comment: You can issue `docker-compose down` even if you started it wiithout `-d` -- in another terminal window.

Answer (score 1):

On a Mac, you might be able to resolve the issue by deleting the `/Users/{your account}/data` folder.

You should be able to find the folder by going to `Finder` -> `Go` -> `Go to Folder` -> And search `~/Users/`.

Other solutions that I tried before this that didn't work:

- stopping and removing all mongo containers
- removing all mongo images
- `Clean / Purge data` from Docker Desktop
- uninstall and reinstall Docker

Answer (score 1):

For me what helped is deleting the mounted host directory, deleting the volume with `docker volume rm {CONTAINER NAME\ID}`.
Make sure to write the volume in compose right, for example:

```
  ...

  database:
    container_name: database
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
    volumes:
      - db:/data/db  
  ...  
  volumes: 
    db:
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Install WSL2 ( It requires recent windows update)
2. Docker  -> Settings -> Enable-> Use WSL 2 based engine

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30487406)

Answer (score 0):

This might be caused by full disk, causing data/ -dir corruption. It's a good idea to have a backup, and restore the data to a clean installation from there.